# JavaFX Textfield data to TableView in different Stage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to input user data from `TextField` in new window into `TableView` in the main window. But it is not populating table, and I'm not getting any Exception. On button clicked new window just closes. I'm creating very simple app just to figure out how to communicate properly between controllers.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    static Stage primaryStage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        this.primaryStage= primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        this.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        this.primaryStage.show();
    }

    public  void closeStage(){
        primaryStage.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller class for main window where are table and button for opening new `Stage`:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML TableView<radnici> tabela;
    @FXML TableColumn<radnici, String> kolona;
    @FXML Button dodajRadnikaDugme;
    @FXML Button closeDugme;

    Main main = new Main();
    static Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene;
    BorderPane borderPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        kolona.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<radnici, String>("ime"));
    }

    public  TableView<radnici> getTabela() {
        return tabela;
    }

    public TableColumn<radnici, String> getKolona() {
        return kolona;
    }

    //Opening new Stage on button clicked
    public void dodajRadnikaDugemKlik() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("dodajRadnika.fxml"));
        borderPane = loader.load();
        scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        stage.setTitle("Dodaj Radnika");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    //Closing main window
    public void closeDugmeKlik(){
        main.closeStage();
    }

    //Method for closing new window
    public  void CloseStage(){
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

Controller class for the new Window where are just `TextField` and Button:

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import java.io.IOException;

public class dodajRadnikaKontroler {
    @FXML TextField upišiRadnika;
    @FXML Button dodajRadnika;

    BorderPane borderPane;

    public void initialize(){
        System.out.println("učitavanje podataka...");
    }

    //Method for adding data on button clicked from TextField into table in main window
    @FXML public void dodajRadnikaKlik() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        ObservableList<radnici> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        lista.add(new radnici(upišiRadnika.getText()));
        controller.tabela.setItems(lista);
        upišiRadnika.clear();
        controller.CloseStage();
    }
}
```

Model Class for workers ("radnici"):

```
package sample;

public class radnici {
    private String ime;

    public radnici(String ime) {
        this.ime = ime;
    }

    public String getIme() {
        return ime;
    }

    public void setIme(String ime) {
        this.ime = ime;
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me so that I can finally do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). I have changed some names of classes so that they follow standard conventions.

You don't see the changes to your table, because you are loading a entire new UI structure from the FXML file, including a new `TableView`, and then you set the items in that new table view.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
borderPane = new BorderPane();

// load a new UI from the FXML file:
borderPane = loader.load();
// get the controller for the new UI:
Controller controller = loader.getController();
ObservableList<radnici> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
lista.add(new radnici(upišiRadnika.getText()));
// set the table items in the new UI:
controller.tabela.setItems(lista);
upišiRadnika.clear();
controller.CloseStage();
```

Since you don't even display this new UI, you don't see the items in the table.

Presumably what you actually want to do is update the items in the existing table. All you need for this is a reference to the table's backing list. You need to pass that to the controller for the second FXML file. Add a field and method to `DodajRadnikaKontroler`:

```
public class DodajRadnikaKontroler {

    // Existing code omitted:

    private ObservableList<Radnici> items ;

    public void setItems(ObservableList<Radnici> items) {
        this.itmes = items ;
    }
}
```

and then pass the table's list to the new controller when you load the FMXL file:

```
//Opening new Stage on button clicked
public void dodajRadnikaDugemKlik() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    borderPane = new BorderPane();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("dodajRadnika.fxml"));
    borderPane = loader.load();

    DodajRadnikaKontroler controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setItems(tabela.getItems());

    scene = new Scene(borderPane);
    stage.setTitle("Dodaj Radnika");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.showAndWait();
}
```

and now in the `dodajRadnikaKlik()` method you just update the list:

```
@FXML public void dodajRadnikaKlik() throws IOException {

    // if you want to add an item:
    items.add(new radnici(upišiRadnika.getText()));

    // if you want to replace all items with the new one:
    // items.setAll(new radnici(upišiRadnika.getText()));

    upišiRadnika.clear();
    controller.CloseStage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is working. I was trying to figure out this for days. But I have somewhat different logic - that is I'm not understanding it completly. When you pass empty list from empty table to parameters in `setItems` method and then update that list `items` in `dodajRadnikaKlik()`with user input, it should be overwriting that list. Why is it populating table's list, i.e. table, and not just `items` list, which is not set to be the table's list? We are using `tabela.getItems` just to pupulate list `items`? How is this list `items` connected to table's list.

Comment: @Kvark900 `tabela.getItems()` gives you a reference to the list that the table is using as its source of data. So if you add something to that list, you add something to the data displayed in the table.